# Powerpoint Userform displaying on wrong monitor in presentation mode

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Problem I am having:  when I click on command button the UserForm1.Show works by showing a stopwatch user form I created but it is showing on the wrong display in presentation mode (it is showing up on my laptop screen which is showing the slide notes instead of the main screen projected to audience).

Tried different things with vba but nothing is working.